# Node,js Websocket Server. How to identify client and send specific data from mysql database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, websocket

i have a problem with websocket serwer in node.js.

I have database in MYSQL. The table named 'users' is holding players ID, life, level etc. How can I know to which client i should send data from database?

In php after sign in i was making session variable like $_SESSION['id'] = id which was connected to password and login in database. And then i was fetching data fromdatabase like: SELECT life in users WHERE ID={$_SESSION['id']}.

How can I do something like this in Node.js websocket server? I mean if value in database is changed it will send new value to specific client and update specific div.

I hope is any solution of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain `$_SESSION` by your self. Like this:

```
const session = {}; // your session.
 wss.on('connection', (conn) => {
    conn.on('message', (message) => {
        switch(message.opreate) {
            case 'login': // your login message
                const user = login(message.account, message.pass);
                session[user.id] = user;
                conn.userId = user.id;
            case 'other': // your other message
              const user = session[conn.userId];
              // ... more code
        }
    })
 })
```

Comment: So I understand that it is server side code?

If so, how can I pass the arguments from client to server (message.account and message.pass)? I have to do this during signing in? After click in 'Sign In' button?

Comment: I think you should learn more about [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)  and the difference between `HTTP` and `WebScoket`.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that it is server side code?

If so, how can I pass the arguments from client to server (message.account and message.pass)? I have to do this during signing in? After click in 'Sign In' button?